# Exception while commiting the code to svn from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

While committing the java file to `svn` in Eclipse I cancelled the process.But when I am again committing the java file to `svn` I am getting the following error from eclipse.

Some resources were not reverted.

```
svn: Error restoring text for '/path/..of/that/file'
```

I have already tried the Cleanup option From Team in Eclipse

Comment: Can you team disconnect and team share it again?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your file has already been committed, if not, take a backup of that file, use revert to revert the file, make your changes and commit.

Comment: While reverting the file back I m getting the following error                   Some resources were not reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the project and take backup of the file and commit again if previous commit was not successful.

Comment: Have already tried this solution receiving the same error  'Some resources were not reverted.'

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of that copy then do update and override action . After that you modify you code and commit again.
Either Try a 'Cleanup'. If that doesn't work you need to do a fresh checkout.